stabilityai/stable-cascade takes 7+ hours to generate an image
I am using this model: https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-cascade
from diffusers import StableCascadeCombinedPipeline

print("LOADING MODEL")
pipe = StableCascadeCombinedPipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-cascade", variant="bf16", torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)
print("MODEL LOADED")

prompt = "a lawyer"
pipe(
    prompt=prompt,
    negative_prompt="",
    num_inference_steps=10,
    prior_num_inference_steps=20,
    prior_guidance_scale=3.0,
    width=1024,
    height=1024,
).images[0].save("cascade-combined2.png")

The model is loaded almost instantly but the next part took 7 plus hours.
Loading pipeline components...: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00,  9.73it/s]
Loading pipeline components...: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████| 6/6 [00:00<00:00, 11.08it/s]
MODEL LOADED
  0%|                                                                                | 0/20 [00:00<?, ?it/s]  0%|                                                                                | 0/20 [04:10<?, ?it/s]

I am using
Apple M2 Pro (32 GB)
Python 3.10.2
Is there anything I can do to speed this up? Becuase I would like to generate maybe 50 images and that doesn't seem possible at the current speed.
Edit:
pipe = StableCascadeCombinedPipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-cascade", variant="bf16", torch_dtype=torch.float32)

device = torch.device('mps')
pipe.to(device)

prompt = "a football"
pipe(
    prompt=prompt,
    negative_prompt="",
    num_inference_steps=10,
    prior_num_inference_steps=20,
    prior_guidance_scale=3.0,
    width=1024,
    height=1024,
).images[0].save("cascade-combined2.png")


You're very likely not running on your GPU, that's why it's so slow.

and how can I achieve that in this case? @Ivan

Have you looked into how to perform computing with PyTorch on a M2 GPU?

Assuming you now have access to your GPU, this can be checked with:
>>> torch.backends.mps.is_available()
>>> torch.backends.mps.is_built()

You can perform inference on that device instead of the CPU:
device = torch.device('mps')
pipe = pipe.to(device)


Edited the qs to add updated code. It ran successfully once but generated a black empty image. However, on the following runs, it keeps giving this error RuntimeError: Placeholder storage has not been allocated on MPS device!

You might have to assign the result of to, can you try this: pipe = pipe.to(device)? Here is the reference documentation for using MPS with  diffusers

that didn't help. but if i wait like 10 mins to start the next run, it works. but if i run soon after the previous run, it doesnt run
